# JavaScript Game Engine -- Code RUNS in Editor :) ERRORS in Inspector?

Tags: javascript, html, compiler-errors, game-engine

### Code RUNS in Editor :)  6 ERRORS in Inspector ??

After developing the game, the document was able to RUN in Dreamweaver and TacoHTML.  When the document was loaded in the w3 Inspector, there were like 6 errors for the  tag styles, and "px" properties.

Once the errors were corrected for CSS3 and HTML5, nothing would RUN!!!  WHY? :(
If anyone can fix these bugs and post answers, the engine is free to use:

THANKS

```
<head> 
<title> Matador </title> 

<style>
#container {background-color:#FC3; position: absolute; width:1024px;     
height:600px; left:0px; top:0px;}
</style>

</head>

<body style="background-color:#F00;">
<div id="container">

<img src="matador.png" id="matador" style="position:absolute; top:200; 
left:100; width:60; height:60;" />

<img src="bull.jpg" id="bull" style="position:absolute; top:300; left:20;   
width:90; height:90;" />

<img id="matadorLife" src="matadorLife.png" style="position:absolute; 
top:605; left:960; width:60; height:60;" />

<div id="scoreId" style="position:absolute; top: 30; left: 30; font-family:    
impact; color:red; font-size: 50; text-shadow: -2px 2px 0 #FFFFFF, 2px -2px   
0 #FFFFFF, 2px 2px 0 #FFFFFF, -2px -2px 0 #FFFFFF;"> </div>

<button type="button" onClick="MoveLeft();" style="position:absolute;   
top:600; left:0; width:150; height:60; font-family: impact; color:red; font-
size: 40; text-shadow: -2px 2px 0 #FFFFFF, 2px -2px 0 #FFFFFF, 2px 2px 0 
#FFFFFF, -2px -2px 0 #FFFFFF; background-color:#FC3; text-align: center;"> 
LEFT </button>


<button type="button" onClick="MoveRight();" style="position:absolute;  
top:600; left:180; width:150; height:60; font-family: impact; color:red; 
font-size: 40; text-shadow: -2px 2px 0 #FFFFFF, 2px -2px 0 #FFFFFF, 2px 2px 
0 #FFFFFF, -2px -2px 0 #FFFFFF; background-color:#FC3; text-align: center;"> 
RIGHT </button>


<button type="button" onClick="MoveDown();" style="position:absolute;   
top:600; left:360; width:150; height:60; font-family: impact; color:red;  
font-size: 40; text-shadow: -2px 2px 0 #FFFFFF, 2px -2px 0 #FFFFFF, 2px 2px 
0 #FFFFFF, -2px -2px 0 #FFFFFF; background-color:#FC3; text-align: center;"> 
DOWN </button>


<button type="button" onClick="MoveUp();" style="position:absolute; top:600;  
left:540; width:150; height:60; font-family: impact; color:red; font-size: 
40; text-shadow: -2px 2px 0 #FFFFFF, 2px -2px 0 #FFFFFF, 2px 2px 0 #FFFFFF, 
-2px -2px 0 #FFFFFF; background-color:#FC3; text-align:center;"> UP 
</button>

</div>

<script>

var matadorObj = document.getElementById("matador").style;
var xMatador = 0;
var yMatador = 0;

var bullObj = document.getElementById("bull").style;
var xBull = 0;
var yBull = 200;

var xSpeed = 10;
var ySpeed = 10;

var score = 0;
var speedInc = 0;

var lifeObj=document.getElementById("matadorLife").style;

document.onkeydown = KeyDownMoveIt;

function KeyDownMoveIt(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 37)
   xMatador = xMatador - 10 - speedInc*10;

   if (e.keyCode == 39)
   xMatador = xMatador + 10 + speedInc*10;

   if (e.keyCode == 38)
   yMatador = yMatador - 10 - speedInc*10;

   if (e.keyCode == 40)
   yMatador = yMatador + 10 + speedInc*10;

   if (xMatador > 970 - 50)
   xMatador = 970 - 50;

   if (yMatador > 550 - 50)
   yMatador = 550 - 50;

   if (xMatador < 40)
   xMatador = 40;

   if (yMatador < 150)
   yMatador = 150;

   matadorObj.left = xMatador;
   matadorObj.top = yMatador;
}


function MoveRight()
{ matadorObj.left = xMatador;
   matadorObj.top = yMatador;
   xMatador = xMatador + 60 + speedInc*10;
    if (xMatador > 970 - 50)
   xMatador = 970 - 50;

   if (yMatador > 550 - 50)
   yMatador = 550 - 50;

   if (xMatador < 40)
   xMatador = 40;

   if (yMatador < 150)
   yMatador = 150;}

function MoveLeft()
{ matadorObj.left = xMatador;
   matadorObj.top = yMatador;
   xMatador = xMatador - 60 - speedInc*10;
    if (xMatador > 970 - 50)
   xMatador = 970 - 50;

   if (yMatador > 550 - 50)
   yMatador = 550 - 50;

   if (xMatador < 40)
   xMatador = 40;

   if (yMatador < 150)
   yMatador = 150;}

function MoveUp()
{ matadorObj.left = xMatador;
   matadorObj.top = yMatador;
   yMatador = yMatador - 60 - speedInc*10;
    if (xMatador > 970 - 50)
   xMatador = 970 - 50;

   if (yMatador > 550 - 50)
   yMatador = 550 - 50;

   if (xMatador < 40)
   xMatador = 40;

   if (yMatador < 150)
   yMatador = 150;}

function MoveDown()
{ matadorObj.left = xMatador;
   matadorObj.top = yMatador;
   yMatador = yMatador + 60 + speedInc*10;
    if (xMatador > 970 - 50)
   xMatador = 970 - 50;

   if (yMatador > 550 - 50)
   yMatador = 550 - 50;

   if (xMatador < 40)
    xMatador = 40;

    if (yMatador < 150)
   yMatador = 150;}


var timerA;
window.onload = moveBull();
function moveBull(){

   if (xBull + xSpeed > 970 - 50)
   xSpeed = -5 * Math.random() - 5 - speedInc;

   if (xBull + xSpeed < 0)
   xSpeed = 5 * Math.random() + 5 + speedInc;

   if (yBull + ySpeed > 550 - 50)
   ySpeed = -5 * Math.random() - 5 - speedInc;

   if (yBull + ySpeed < 0)
   ySpeed = 5 * Math.random() + 5 + speedInc;

   xBull = xBull + xSpeed;
   yBull = yBull + ySpeed;

   bullObj.left = xBull;
   bullObj.top = yBull;

   speedInc = score * 0.01;

   if ((xMatador < xBull+50) && (xMatador+50 > xBull) && (yMatador <     
yBull+50) && (yMatador+50 > yBull))

 {
      clearTimeout(timerB);
      matadorObj.src="matadorLost.png";
      bullObj.src="bullWon.png";
      document.getElementById("scoreId").innerHTML = "- GAME OVER -";
      document.getElementById("container").style.backgroundColor="red"; 
      lifeObj.visibility="hidden"; }

   if (score == 31) {clearTimeout(timerB);
      document.getElementById("container").style.backgroundColor="yellow";
      matadorObj.src="matadorWon.png";
      bullObj.src="bullLost.png";
      document.getElementById("scoreId").innerHTML = "- WINNER! -";}

   timerA = setTimeout("moveBull()", 30);}

var timerB;
window.onload = gameScore();
function gameScore() {  

   document.getElementById("scoreId").innerHTML = "MATADOR <br>" + score; 
   score++;
   timerB = setTimeout("gameScore()", 1000);}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### End of Engine

Comment: What were the errors? What do you mean with 'nothing would run'? Please give us a bit more information, don't expect we will just write your code for you ;)

Comment: In HTML5 style properties like `top` and `left` need an unit like `px` to work.

Comment: The person that can fix this Engine is a Genius! :)

Comment: To: Erik Dolor >  The document was able to RUN the style properties and JavaScript functions in Dreamweaver CS6, Dreamweaver CC, and TacoHTMLEdit.  Once the Engine was pasted in w3 Inspector or tested in DropBox, the document showed ERRORS :(  I would love to figure this out.

Comment: To: Teemu >  I had re-written the Engine for HTML5 and CSS3, but then JavaScript functions have ERRORS.  See Answer :

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head lang="en"> 
<title> Matador </title> 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, 
maximum-scale=1.0"> 

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/> 

<style type="text/css">
#container {background-color:#FC3; position: absolute; width:960px;  
height:600px; left:0px; top:0px;}
</style>

</head>

<body style="background-color:#F00;">
<div id="container">

<img src="matador.png" id="matador" alt="Matador"   
style="position:absolute; top:120px; left:40px; width:50px; height:50px;"/>

<img src="bull.png" id="bull" alt="Bull" style="position:absolute; 
top:250px; left:400px; width:50px; height:50px;"/>

<div id="scoreId" style="position:absolute; top: 30px; left: 30px; font- 
family: impact; color:red; font-size: 50px; text-shadow: -2px 2px 0px 
#FFFFFF, 2px -2px 0px #FFFFFF, 2px 2px 0px #FFFFFF, -2px -2px 0px #FFFFFF;">   
</div>

<img id="matadorLife" src="matadorLife.png" style="position:absolute;  
top:605px; left:840px; width:50px; height:50px;" alt="MatadorLife"/>


<button type="button" onClick="MoveLeft();" style="position:absolute;   
top:600px; left:40px; width:150px; height:60px; font-family: impact; 
color:red; font-size: 40px; text-shadow: -2px 2px 0 #FFFFFF, 2px -2px 0 
#FFFFFF, 2px 2px 0 #FFFFFF, -2px -2px 0 #FFFFFF; background-color:#FC3;  
text-align: center;"> LEFT </button>

<button type="button" onClick="MoveRight();" style="position:absolute;   
top:600px; left:240px; width:150px; height:60px; font-family: impact;  
color:red; font-size: 40px; text-shadow: -2px 2px 0px #FFFFFF, 2px -2px 0px  
#FFFFFF, 2px 2px 0px #FFFFFF, -2px -2px 0px #FFFFFF; background-color:#FC3; 
text-align: center;"> RIGHT </button>


<button type="button" onClick="MoveDown();" style="position:absolute; 
top:600px; left:440px; width:150px; height:60px; font-family: impact; 
color:red; font-size: 40px; text-shadow: -2px 2px 0px #FFFFFF, 2px -2px 0px 
#FFFFFF, 2px 2px 0px #FFFFFF, -2px -2px 0px #FFFFFF; background-color:#FC3; 
text-align: center;"> DOWN </button>


<button type="button" onClick="MoveUp();" style="position:absolute;   
top:600px; left:640px; width:150px; height:60px; font-family: impact; 
color:red; font-size: 40px; text-shadow: -2px 2px 0px #FFFFFF, 2px -2px 0px 
#FFFFFF, 2px 2px 0px #FFFFFF, -2px -2px 0px #FFFFFF; background-color:#FC3;  
text-align:center;"> UP </button>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var matadorObj = document.getElementById("matador").style;
var xMatador = 0;
var yMatador = 0;

var bullObj = document.getElementById("bull").style;
var xBull = 0;
var yBull = 200;

var xSpeed = 10;
var ySpeed = 10;

var score = 0;
var speedInc = 0;

var lifeObj=document.getElementById("matadorLife").style;

function MoveRight()
{ matadorObj.left = xMatador;
   matadorObj.top = yMatador;
   xMatador = xMatador + 40 + speedInc*10;
    if (xMatador > 900 - 50)
   {xMatador = 900 - 50;}

   if (yMatador > 600 - 50)
   {yMatador = 600 - 50;}

   if (xMatador < 40)
   {xMatador = 40;}

   if (yMatador < 150)
   {yMatador = 150;}}

function MoveLeft()
{ matadorObj.left = xMatador;
   matadorObj.top = yMatador;
   xMatador = xMatador - 40 - speedInc*10;
    if (xMatador > 900 - 50)
   {xMatador = 900 - 50;}

   if (yMatador > 600 - 50)
   {yMatador = 600 - 50;}

   if (xMatador < 40)
   {xMatador = 40;}

    if (yMatador < 150)
   {yMatador = 150;}}

function MoveUp()
{ matadorObj.left = xMatador;
   matadorObj.top = yMatador;
   yMatador = yMatador - 40 - speedInc*10;
    if (xMatador > 900 - 50)
   {xMatador = 900 - 50;}

   if (yMatador > 600 - 50)
   {yMatador = 600 - 50;}

   if (xMatador < 40)
   {xMatador = 40;}

   if (yMatador < 150)
   {yMatador = 150;}}

function MoveDown()
{ matadorObj.left = xMatador;
   matadorObj.top = yMatador;
   yMatador = yMatador + 40 + speedInc*10;
    if (xMatador > 900 - 50)
   {xMatador = 900 - 50;}

   if (yMatador > 600 - 50)
   {yMatador = 600 - 50;}

   if (xMatador < 40)
   {xMatador = 40;}

   if (yMatador < 150)
   {yMatador = 150;}}


var timerA;
window.onload = moveBull();
function moveBull(){

   if (xBull + xSpeed > 900 - 50)
   {xSpeed = -5 * Math.random() - 5 - speedInc;}

   if (xBull + xSpeed < 0)
   {xSpeed = 5 * Math.random() + 5 + speedInc;}

   if (yBull + ySpeed > 600 - 50)
   {ySpeed = -5 * Math.random() - 5 - speedInc;}

   if (yBull + ySpeed < 0)
   {ySpeed = 5 * Math.random() + 5 + speedInc;}

   xBull = xBull + xSpeed;
   yBull = yBull + ySpeed;

   bullObj.left = xBull;
   bullObj.top = yBull;

   speedInc = score * 0.01;

   if ((xMatador < xBull+50) && (xMatador+50 > xBull) && (yMatador <     
yBull+50) && (yMatador+50 > yBull))
   {clearTimeout(timerB);
      matadorObj.src="matadorLost.png";
      bullObj.src="bullWon.png";
      document.getElementById("scoreId").innerHTML = "- GAME OVER -"; 
      lifeObj.visibility="hidden"; }

   if (score == 61) {clearTimeout(timerB);
      document.getElementById("container").style.backgroundColor="red";
      matadorObj.src="matadorWon.png";
      bullObj.src="bullLost.png";}

   timerA = setTimeout("moveBull()", 20);}

var timerB;
window.onload = gameScore();
function gameScore() {  

   document.getElementById("scoreId").innerHTML = "MATADOR <br>" + score; 
   score++;
   timerB = setTimeout("gameScore()", 1000);}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now when I RUN this Engine for HTML5 / CSS3, the container and buttons elements still work but the JavaScript functions won't RUN for the sprites :(